# Continuous Assignment of a net with Class member as driver

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have an interface net, which needs to be assigned with class member.

However, I am not sure, how to do this, as I have tried with `always_comb`, which passes in compilation, but still doesn't do continuous assignments. `assign` statement does not work.

```
interface analog ();
  bit [10:0] r;
endinterface

class abc;
  bit [10:0] t;
endclass

module temp();
  abc a1;

  analog a2 ();

  always_comb begin
    a2.r = a1.t;
  end

  initial begin
    a1 = new();
    a1.t = 10'd35;
    $display("a1.t - %0d, a2.r - %0d", a1.t, a2.r);
    #1;
    a1.t = 10'd21;
    $display("a1.t - %0d, a2.r - %0d", a1.t, a2.r);
    #1;
    a1.t = 10'd67;
    $display("a1.t - %0d, a2.r - %0d", a1.t, a2.r);
  end
endmodule

// Result - 
a1.t - 35, a2.r - 0
a1.t - 21, a2.r - 35
a1.t - 67, a2.r - 35
```

As you can see that `a2.r` is only assigned once and no further assignments are done.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Try `always @( a1.t )`

Comment: Had tried that. Doesn't work. Gives error of `null`pointer for `a1`.

Comment: Works for me using Xilinx Vivado 2018.2.

Comment: I am trying in Cadence Xcelium and doesn't work. It seems genuine error, because always block will start waiting from time 0, even before `a1` object is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems with this code.

1. You have a race condition between the construction of a1 and its first reference. `assign` is not allowed because a null reference is likely
2. The `always_comb` is sensitive to the class variable `a1` changing, not any of its members.
3. Your `$display` statements are placed so not to see the updated values of t.

Try this:

```
module temp();
  abc a1;

  analog a2 ();

  initial wait(a1 != null)
    forever begin
       a2.r = a1.t;
       @a1.t;
    end

  initial begin
    a1    = new();
    a1.t  = 10'd35;
    #1 $display("a1.t - %0d, a2.r - %0d", a1.t, a2.r);
    a1.t = 10'd21;
    #1 $display("a1.t - %0d, a2.r - %0d", a1.t, a2.r);
    a1.t = 10'd67;
    #1 $display("a1.t - %0d, a2.r - %0d", a1.t, a2.r);
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Yes. Just few mins ago, I had thought of the same and tried this. It works. However in my original testbench, the variable is deep down in hierarchy and hence this workaround is bit cumbersome. I can implement this, but is there any other way for this issue?

Comment: Which variable is deep down?

Comment: This is just a small example, but `a1.t` is deep down.

Comment: That much easier than if `a2.r` was deep down. All you have to do is copy the handle. But would need to see more code to know why you think that is an issue.

Comment: No. Even though if I copy the handle, but still in the wait condition, I'll need to write the entire hierarchy not null like `p1 != null && p1.p2 != null && p1.p2.p3 != null && p1.p2.p3.a1 != null`. And this is cumbersome, error prone and for long hierarchy quite unreliable.

Comment: If you were using the UVM, this would be easy. if not, you could have the code that constructs p3 write to a global variable. and then this code waits for the global variable not to be null. Again, without any more code, its hard to suggest the most efficient answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help @dave_59. We can pass that handle to the top level module and then only use the handle for null check. Or 2nd option is, we can make macros for hierarchical null check conditions with reuse of macros. I have opted for 2nd solution. Thanks :)